# Diferecias entre bibliotecas OMP y MPI en programación en paralelo

Tags: c, hilos

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre la biblioteca de OMP y MPI de C ? Si ambas sirven para programas de cómputo en paralelo

Answer (score 5):

La **principal** diferencia esta en la **arquitectura** del sistema paralelo: **MPI** se utiliza para sistemas de **memoria distribuida**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mientras que  **OMP** se utiliza en sistemas de **memoria compartida**
[image: Arquitectura de OMP]

La **comunicación de procesos** en  MPI es a través del paso de mensajes, mientras que en OMP no es necesaria la comunicación entre procesos, ya que todos los hilos comparten la memoria.
OMP ayuda a paralelizar un programa, por medio de directivas:

- omp_get_num_threads()
- omp_get_thread_num()

Muchas de ellas son variables del entorno que se establecen en **tiempo de compilación**. 
Mientras que en **MPI** el programador es el principal encargado de paralelizar el programa mediante en uso de las siguientes funciones:

- MPI_Init()
- MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
- MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
- MPI_Finalize()

A continuación dejo dos sensillos ejemplos:

Implementación OpenMP

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(){
  int nthreads, tid;
#pragma omp parallel private(nthreads,tid)
{
  tid = omp_get_thread_num();

  printf("Hola Mundo. Soy el hilo %d\n", tid);
  if (tid==0){
      nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
      printf("Número de hilos: %d\n",nthreads);
  }

}
  return 0;
}
```

Implementación MPI:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int rank;
  int size;
  MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  printf ("Soy el nodo %d de un cluster de %d\n", rank, size);
  MPI_Finalize ();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para complementar, en MPI el programador se encarga de toda la logística de cómo serán las comunicaciones mientras que en OpenMP no.  Adicionalmente, dependiendo de la implementación de MPI, hay funciones que trabajan con memoria compartida como lo trabaja OpenMP.